# Missing JS files in WorkExecution app of Maximo Anywhere 7.5.2.1 4Q release

Tags: maximo-anywhere

I have updated MaximoAnywhere 7.5.2.1 with the latest release 4Q from ISM library.
After building the apps and deployed the WorkExecution App, I could only see blank screen.
Console log complains about two missing JS files
1.CopyPlansToActualsHandler.js
2.CrewUtil.js
Just to make framework happy, I copied over the CopyPlansToActualHandler.js from IssuesandReturns app, and created a dummy CrewUtil.js file.
After this, I was presented with the login screen and able to get into the WorkExecution App.

```
   http://10.1.152.114:10080/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/1.0/default/js/application/handlers/CopyPlansToActualsHandler.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
            dojo.js:2 Error: scriptError(…)(anonymous function) @ dojo.js:2
                http://10.1.152.114:10080/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/1.0/default/js/application/business/util/CrewUtil.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
            dojo.js:2 Error: scriptError(…)
```

Answer (score 0):

These files should already exist in the 7.5.2.1 release in the application component.  I suspect you're on a Mac?  If you use finder to merge a directory into Mac, it will REMOVE files from the destination directory that don't exist in the source directory.  That's why those "ditto" instructions are in the ISM Library README.  If this is the case, then the safest thing to do, is to restore the 7521 version of the MaximoAnywhere directory, and reapply the ISMLibrary app.zip using the "ditto" instructions in the ISMLibrary README.

Comment: I have followed the ditto instructions. However, I would try one more time

Comment: Having same issue on Windows platform too.